# Inheritance and Super Classes in Python not working

Tags: python, inheritance, super

Morning all,

I'm an A level computer science teacher, and with their pre-release material exam coming up they're busy beavering away trying to make things work.

I don't teach the programming side of the course, focusing on the theory, and their programming teacher has been off ill for a while so I'm doing what I can but running out of time to support the top end.

Their pre-release material in Python is based on a foxes and rabbits game, and one of the pupils is trying to make a class called 'GiantWarren' that inherits the properties and functions of warren, but is a larger instance.

His code is below, and he's using 'super' to try and inherit the functions of warren, but it won't work unless he copy and pastes the functions. Any help on how to get super working would be greatly appreciated, not just by me, but my pupils as well:

Note - Warren is line 228, GiantWarren is line 351

```
#Skeleton Program code for the AQA A Level Paper 1 2017 examination
#this code should be used in conjunction with the Preliminary Material
#written by the AQA Programmer Team
#developed in the Python 3.4.1 programming environment

import enum
import random
import math

class Location:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Fox = None
    self.Warren = None

class Simulation:
  def __init__(self, LandscapeSize, InitialWarrenCount, InitialFoxCount, Variability, FixedInitialLocations):
    self.__ViewRabbits = ""
    self.__TimePeriod = 0
    self.__WarrenCount = 0
    self.__FoxCount = 0
    self.__ShowDetail = False
    self.__LandscapeSize = LandscapeSize
    self.__Variability = Variability
    self.__FixedInitialLocations = FixedInitialLocations
    self.__Landscape = []
    for Count1 in range (self.__LandscapeSize):
      LandscapeRow = []
      for Count2 in range (self.__LandscapeSize):
        LandscapeLocation = None
        LandscapeRow.append(LandscapeLocation)
      self.__Landscape.append(LandscapeRow)
    self.__CreateLandscapeAndAnimals(InitialWarrenCount, InitialFoxCount, self.__FixedInitialLocations)
    self.__DrawLandscape()
    MenuOption = 0
    while (self.__WarrenCount > 0 or self.__FoxCount > 0) and MenuOption != 5:
      print()
      print("0. Advance 10 time periods hiding detail")
      print("1. Advance to next time period showing detail")
      print("2. Advance to next time period hiding detail")
      print("3. Inspect fox")
      print("4. Inspect warren")
      print("5. Exit")
      print()
      try:
        MenuOption = int(input("Select option: "))
      except:
        print("What you have entered is not an integer. Try again")
      if MenuOption == 0:
        for a in range(1, 11):
          self.__TimePeriod += 1
          self.__ShowDetail = False
          self.__AdvanceTimePeriod()
      if MenuOption == 1:
        self.__TimePeriod += 1
        self.__ShowDetail = True
        self.__AdvanceTimePeriod()
      if MenuOption == 2:
        self.__TimePeriod += 1
        self.__ShowDetail = False
        self.__AdvanceTimePeriod()
      if MenuOption == 3:
        x = self.__InputCoordinate("x")
        y = self.__InputCoordinate("y")
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox is None:
          self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.Inspect()
      if MenuOption == 4:
        x = self.__InputCoordinate("x")
        y = self.__InputCoordinate("y")
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren is None:
          self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.Inspect()
          self.__ViewRabbits = input("View individual rabbits (y/n)? ")
          if self.__ViewRabbits == "y":
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.ListRabbits()
    input()

  def __InputCoordinate(self, CoordinateName):
    Coordinate = int(input("  Input " + CoordinateName + " coordinate:"))
    return Coordinate

  def __AdvanceTimePeriod(self):
    NewFoxCount = 0
    if self.__ShowDetail:
      print()
    for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      for y in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren is None:
          if self.__ShowDetail:
            print("Warren at (", x, ",", y, "):", sep = "")
            print("  Period Start: ", end = "")
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.Inspect()
          if self.__FoxCount > 0:
            self.__FoxesEatRabbitsInWarren(x, y)
          if self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.NeedToCreateNewWarren():
            self.__CreateNewWarren()
          self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.AdvanceGeneration(self.__ShowDetail)
          if self.__ShowDetail:
            print("  Period End: ", end = "")
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.Inspect()
            input()
          if self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.WarrenHasDiedOut():
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren = None
            self.__WarrenCount -= 1
    for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      for y in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox is None:
          if self.__ShowDetail:
            print("Fox at (", x, ",", y, "): ", sep = "")
          self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.AdvanceGeneration(self.__ShowDetail)
          if self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.CheckIfDead():
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox = None
            self.__FoxCount -= 1
          else:
            if self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.ReproduceThisPeriod():
              if self.__ShowDetail:
                print("  Fox has reproduced. ")
              NewFoxCount += 1
            if self.__ShowDetail:
              self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.Inspect()
            self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox.ResetFoodConsumed()
    if NewFoxCount > 0:
      if self.__ShowDetail:
        print("New foxes born: ")
      for f in range (0, NewFoxCount):
        self.__CreateNewFox()
    if self.__ShowDetail:
      input()
    self.__DrawLandscape()
    print()

  def __CreateLandscapeAndAnimals(self, InitialWarrenCount, InitialFoxCount, FixedInitialLocations):
    for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      for y in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
        self.__Landscape[x][y] = Location()
    if FixedInitialLocations:
      self.__Landscape[1][1].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability, 38)
      self.__Landscape[2][8].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability, 80) 
      self.__Landscape[9][7].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability, 20)
      self.__Landscape[10][3].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability, 52)
      self.__Landscape[13][4].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability, 67)
      self.__Landscape[11][4].Warren = GiantWarren(self.__Variability, 115)
      self.__WarrenCount = 6
      self.__Landscape[2][10].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
      self.__Landscape[6][1].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
      self.__Landscape[8][6].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
      self.__Landscape[11][13].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
      self.__Landscape[12][4].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
      self.__FoxCount = 5
    else:
      for w in range (0, InitialWarrenCount):
        self.__CreateNewWarren()
      for f in range (0, InitialFoxCount):
        self.__CreateNewFox()

  def __CreateNewWarren(self):
    x = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    y = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    while not self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren is None:
      x = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
      y = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    if self.__ShowDetail:
      print("New Warren at (", x, ",", y, ")", sep = "")
    self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren = Warren(self.__Variability)
    self.__WarrenCount += 1

  def __CreateNewFox(self):
    x = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    y = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    while not self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox is None:
      x = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
      y = random.randint(0, self.__LandscapeSize - 1)
    if self.__ShowDetail:
      print("  New Fox at (", x, ",", y, ")", sep = "")
    self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox = Fox(self.__Variability)
    self.__FoxCount += 1

  def __FoxesEatRabbitsInWarren(self, WarrenX, WarrenY):
    RabbitCountAtStartOfPeriod  = self.__Landscape[WarrenX][WarrenY].Warren.GetRabbitCount()
    for FoxX in range(0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      for FoxY in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
        if not self.__Landscape[FoxX][FoxY].Fox is None:
          Dist = self.__DistanceBetween(FoxX, FoxY, WarrenX, WarrenY)
          if Dist <= 3.5:
            PercentToEat = 20
          elif Dist <= 7:
            PercentToEat = 10
          else:
            PercentToEat = 0
          RabbitsToEat = int(round(float(PercentToEat * RabbitCountAtStartOfPeriod / 100)))
          FoodConsumed = self.__Landscape[WarrenX][WarrenY].Warren.EatRabbits(RabbitsToEat)
          self.__Landscape[FoxX][FoxY].Fox.GiveFood(FoodConsumed)
          if self.__ShowDetail:
            print("  ", FoodConsumed, " rabbits eaten by fox at (", FoxX, ",", FoxY, ").", sep = "")

  def __DistanceBetween(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2)))

  def __DrawLandscape(self):
    print()
    print("TIME PERIOD:", self.__TimePeriod)
    print()
    print("   ", end = "")
    for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      if x < 10:
        print(" ", end = "")
      print(x, "|", end = "")
    print()
    for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize * 4 + 3):
      print("-", end = "")
    print()
    for y in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
      if y < 10:
        print(" ", end = "")
      print("", y, "|", sep = "", end = "")
      for x in range (0, self.__LandscapeSize):
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren is None:
          if self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.GetRabbitCount() < 10:
            print(" ", end = "")
          print(self.__Landscape[x][y].Warren.GetRabbitCount(), end = "")
        else:
          print("  ", end = "")
        if not self.__Landscape[x][y].Fox is None:
          print("F", end = "")
        else:
          print(" ", end = "")
        print("|", end = "")
      print()

class Warren:
  def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount = 0):
    self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN = 99
    self.__RabbitCount = RabbitCount
    self.__PeriodsRun = 0
    self.__AlreadySpread = False
    self.__Variability = Variability
    self.__Rabbits = []
    for Count in range(0, self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN):
      self.__Rabbits.append(None)
    if self.__RabbitCount == 0:
      self.__RabbitCount = int(self.__CalculateRandomValue(int(self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN / 4), self.__Variability))
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      self.__Rabbits[r] = Rabbit(self.__Variability)

  def __CalculateRandomValue(self, BaseValue, Variability):
    return BaseValue - (BaseValue * Variability / 100) + (BaseValue * random.randint(0, Variability * 2) / 100)

  def GetRabbitCount(self): 
    return self.__RabbitCount

  def NeedToCreateNewWarren(self): 
    if self.__RabbitCount == self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN and not self.__AlreadySpread:
      self.__AlreadySpread = True
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def WarrenHasDiedOut(self):
    if self.__RabbitCount == 0:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def AdvanceGeneration(self, ShowDetail):
    self.__PeriodsRun += 1
    if self.__RabbitCount > 0:
      self.__KillByOtherFactors(ShowDetail)
    if self.__RabbitCount > 0:
      self.__AgeRabbits(ShowDetail)
    if self.__RabbitCount > 0 and self.__RabbitCount <= self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN:
      if self.__ContainsMales():
        self.__MateRabbits(ShowDetail)
    if self.__RabbitCount == 0 and ShowDetail:
      print("  All rabbits in warren are dead")

  def EatRabbits(self, RabbitsToEat):
    DeathCount = 0
    if RabbitsToEat > self.__RabbitCount:
      RabbitsToEat = self.__RabbitCount
    while DeathCount < RabbitsToEat:
      RabbitNumber = random.randint(0, self.__RabbitCount - 1)
      if not self.__Rabbits[RabbitNumber] is None:
        self.__Rabbits[RabbitNumber] = None
        DeathCount += 1
    self.__CompressRabbitList(DeathCount)
    return RabbitsToEat

  def __KillByOtherFactors(self, ShowDetail):
    DeathCount = 0
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      if self.__Rabbits[r].CheckIfKilledByOtherFactor():
        self.__Rabbits[r] = None
        DeathCount += 1
    self.__CompressRabbitList(DeathCount)
    if ShowDetail:
      print(" ", DeathCount, "rabbits killed by other factors.")

  def __AgeRabbits(self, ShowDetail):
    DeathCount = 0
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      self.__Rabbits[r].CalculateNewAge()
      if self.__Rabbits[r].CheckIfDead():
        self.__Rabbits[r] = None
        DeathCount += 1
    self.__CompressRabbitList(DeathCount)
    if ShowDetail:
      print(" ", DeathCount, "rabbits die of old age.")

  def __MateRabbits(self, ShowDetail):
    Mate = 0
    Babies = 0 
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      if self.__Rabbits[r].IsFemale() and self.__RabbitCount + Babies < self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN:
        Mate = random.randint(0, self.__RabbitCount - 1)
        while Mate == r or self.__Rabbits[Mate].IsFemale():
          Mate = random.randint(0, self.__RabbitCount - 1)
        CombinedReproductionRate = (self.__Rabbits[r].GetReproductionRate() + self.__Rabbits[Mate].GetReproductionRate()) / 2
        if CombinedReproductionRate >= 1:
          self.__Rabbits[self.__RabbitCount + Babies] = Rabbit(self.__Variability, CombinedReproductionRate)
          Babies += 1
    self.__RabbitCount = self.__RabbitCount + Babies
    if ShowDetail:
      print(" ", Babies, "baby rabbits born.")

  def __CompressRabbitList(self, DeathCount):
    if DeathCount > 0:
      ShiftTo = 0
      ShiftFrom  = 0
      while ShiftTo < self.__RabbitCount - DeathCount:
        while self.__Rabbits[ShiftFrom] is None:
          ShiftFrom += 1
        if ShiftTo != ShiftFrom:
          self.__Rabbits[ShiftTo] = self.__Rabbits[ShiftFrom]
        ShiftTo += 1
        ShiftFrom += 1
      self.__RabbitCount = self.__RabbitCount - DeathCount

  def __ContainsMales(self):
    Males = False
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      if not self.__Rabbits[r].IsFemale():
        Males = True
    return Males

  def Inspect(self):
    print("Periods Run", self.__PeriodsRun, "Size", self.__RabbitCount)

  def ListRabbits(self):
    if self.__RabbitCount > 0:
      for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
        self.__Rabbits[r].Inspect()

class GiantWarren(Warren):
  def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount = 1):
    super(GiantWarren, self).__init__(self.__RabbitCount, Variability)
    self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN = 200
    self.__RabbitCount = RabbitCount
    self.__PeriodsRun = 0
    self.__Variability = Variability
    self.__Rabbits = []

    for Count in range(0, self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN):
      self.__Rabbits.append(None)
    if self.__RabbitCount == 1:
      self.__RabbitCount = int(self.__CalculateRandomValue(int(self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN / 4), self.__Variability))
    for r in range (0, self.__RabbitCount):
      self.__Rabbits[r] = Rabbit(self.__Variability)

class Animal:
  _ID = 1

  def __init__(self, AvgLifespan, AvgProbabilityOfDeathOtherCauses, Variability):
    self._NaturalLifespan = int(AvgLifespan * self._CalculateRandomValue(100, Variability) / 100)
    self._ProbabilityOfDeathOtherCauses = AvgProbabilityOfDeathOtherCauses * self._CalculateRandomValue(100, Variability) / 100
    self._IsAlive = True
    self._ID = Animal._ID
    self._Age = 0
    Animal._ID += 1

  def CalculateNewAge(self):
    self._Age += 1
    if self._Age >= self._NaturalLifespan:
      self._IsAlive = False

  def CheckIfDead(self): 
    return not self._IsAlive

  def Inspect(self):
    print("  ID", self._ID, "", end = "")
    print("Age", self._Age, "", end = "")
    print("LS", self._NaturalLifespan, "", end = "")
    print("Pr dth", round(self._ProbabilityOfDeathOtherCauses, 2), "", end = "")

  def CheckIfKilledByOtherFactor(self):
    if random.randint(0, 100) < self._ProbabilityOfDeathOtherCauses * 100:
      self._IsAlive = False
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def _CalculateRandomValue(self, BaseValue, Variability):
    return BaseValue - (BaseValue * Variability / 100) + (BaseValue * random.randint(0, Variability * 2) / 100)

class Fox(Animal):
  def __init__(self, Variability, genderRatio = 33):
    self.__DEFAULT_LIFE_SPAN = 7
    self.__DEFAULT_PROBABILITY_DEATH_OTHER_CAUSES = 0.1
    super(Fox, self).__init__(self.__DEFAULT_LIFE_SPAN, self.__DEFAULT_PROBABILITY_DEATH_OTHER_CAUSES, Variability)
    self.__FoodUnitsNeeded = int(10 * self._CalculateRandomValue(100, Variability) / 100)
    self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod  = 0
    if random.randint(0, 100) < genderRatio:
      self.__Gender = Genders.Male
    else:
      self.__Gender = Genders.Female


  def AdvanceGeneration(self, ShowDetail):
    if self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod == 0:
      self._IsAlive = False
      if ShowDetail:
        print("  Fox dies as has eaten no food this period.")
    else:
      if self.CheckIfKilledByOtherFactor():
        self._IsAlive = False
        if ShowDetail:
          print("  Fox killed by other factor.")
      else:
        if self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod < self.__FoodUnitsNeeded:
          self.CalculateNewAge()
          if ShowDetail:
            print("  Fox ages further due to lack of food.")
        self.CalculateNewAge()
        if not self._IsAlive:
          if ShowDetail:
            print("  Fox has died of old age.")

  def ResetFoodConsumed(self):
    self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod = 0

  def ReproduceThisPeriod(self): 
    REPRODUCTION_PROBABILITY  = 0.25
    if self.__Gender == Genders.Female:
      if random.randint(0, 100) < REPRODUCTION_PROBABILITY * 100:
        return True
      else:
        return False

  def GiveFood(self, FoodUnits):
    self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod = self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod + FoodUnits

  def IsFemale(self):
    if self.__Gender == Genders.Female:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def Inspect(self):
    super(Fox, self).Inspect()
    print("Food needed", self.__FoodUnitsNeeded, "", end = "")
    print("Food eaten", self.__FoodUnitsConsumedThisPeriod, "", end = "")
    if self.__Gender == Genders.Male:
      gender = "Male"
    else:
      gender = "Female"
    print("Gender", gender, "", end="")
    print()

class Genders(enum.Enum):
  Male = 1
  Female = 2

class Rabbit(Animal):
  def __init__(self, Variability, ParentsReproductionRate = 1.2, genderRatio=50):
    self.__DEFAULT_LIFE_SPAN = 4
    self.__DEFAULT_PROBABILITY_DEATH_OTHER_CAUSES  = 0.05
    super(Rabbit, self).__init__(self.__DEFAULT_LIFE_SPAN, self.__DEFAULT_PROBABILITY_DEATH_OTHER_CAUSES, Variability)
    self.__ReproductionRate = ParentsReproductionRate * self._CalculateRandomValue(100, Variability) / 100
    if random.randint(0, 100) < genderRatio:
      self.__Gender = Genders.Male
    else:
      self.__Gender = Genders.Female

  def Inspect(self):
    super(Rabbit, self).Inspect()
    print("Rep rate", round(self.__ReproductionRate, 1), "", end = "")
    if self.__Gender == Genders.Female:
      print("Gender Female")
    else:
      print("Gender Male")

  def IsFemale(self):
    if self.__Gender == Genders.Female:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def GetReproductionRate(self): 
    return self.__ReproductionRate

def Main():
  MenuOption = 0
  while MenuOption != 3:
    print("Predator Prey Simulation Main Menu")
    print()
    print("1. Run simulation with default settings")
    print("2. Run simulation with custom settings")
    print("3. Rabbit Paradise")
    print("4. Exit")
    print()
    try:
      MenuOption = int(input("Select option: "))
    except:
      print("What you have entered is not an integer. Try again")
    if MenuOption == 1 or MenuOption == 2 or MenuOption == 3:
      if MenuOption == 1:
        LandscapeSize = 15
        InitialWarrenCount = 5
        InitialFoxCount = 5
        Variability = 0
        FixedInitialLocations = True
      elif MenuOption == 3:
        LandscapeSize = 20
        InitialWarrenCount = 20
        InitialFoxCount = 0
        Variability = 1
        FixedInitialLocations = False
      else:
        LandscapeSize = int(input("Landscape Size: "))
        InitialWarrenCount = int(input("Initial number of warrens: "))
        InitialFoxCount = int(input("Initial number of foxes: "))
        Variability = int(input("Randomness variability (percent): "))
        FixedInitialLocations = False
      Sim = Simulation(LandscapeSize, InitialWarrenCount, InitialFoxCount, Variability, FixedInitialLocations)
  input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main()
```

Comment: you should reduce your code to a [mcve]: it's unreadable as-is

Comment: This is python-2.x?

Comment: Next time, please try to reduce the problem space by throwing away everything you can such that the error still occurs. As a teacher, you should know that you did not ask a good question here.

Comment: Apologies, I thought supplying the whole code would assist with working out the errors, and I don't trust myself to trim it with not being a programming expert! Willem - It's Python 3.3.

Comment: And timegb, as a teacher my focus is on the theory not the coding, and with the coding teacher being off, I'm struggling to manage...! It may be a poor question but I asked more out of depseration than anything else! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the indiscriminate use of double-underscore prefixes on the method and attribute names. That's used to invoke name mangling and is specifically intended to *prevent* inheritance; it provides the closest thing to "private" variables that Python has.

The student definitely does not want to use it anywhere here; generally, I recommend never using it at all. Just give everything normal names.

(Note also, since they're programming Python, they should use Python conventions for naming: variables, attributes and methods should have `lower_case_with_underscore` names, not CamelCase which is intended for class names.)

Comment: You are pretty fast.